# Is a plain string valid JSON?

Tags: json

Is a plain string valid JSON or does there have to be an object?

For example:

```
"morpheus"
```

versus:

```
{
    "name": "morpheus"
}
```

Comment: http://jsonlint.com

Comment: Yes, it is. Try `JSON.parse("\"hello world\"")` or `JSON.parse(5)`.

Comment: I'd like to point out that the [ECMA standard document](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) (almost) starts out defining what a JSON **value** is, and that includes string and number literals as well as `true`, `false` and `null`. And, of course, arrays and objects. This is what makes @CRAM and [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com) etc. right.

Comment: Also https://www.json.org/ states that a JSON `value` may be an `object`, `array`, `string`, `number`, `true`, `false`, or `null`. It then describes how `object` and `array` are composed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ## Important
>
> This answer once said No, the first character of the JSON must be a `{` or a `[`.
>
> At the time I wrote that, I was testing it with Python. In Python (2.7.x at least), `json.loads("a")` gives an error, which means that a plain string is not valid JSON there.
>
> It has been rightfully pointed out by others that it cannot be said that a plain string is not valid JSON. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487869/is-this-simple-string-considered-valid-json) for a more appropriate answer.
>
> At this time all I can say is that it depends on your environment. In javascript it may be valid, in python it may not be, etc, etc.

JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation

Here is a quote from [the official site](http://json.org/)

> JSON is built on two structures:
>
> A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is
>   realized as an object, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed
>   list, or associative array. An ordered list of values. In most
>   languages, this is realized as an array, vector, list, or sequence.
>   These are universal data structures. Virtually all modern programming
>   languages support them in one form or another. It makes sense that a
>   data format that is interchangeable with programming languages also be
>   based on these structures.
>
> In JSON, they take on these forms:
>
> **An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs. An object begins**
>   **with { (left brace) and ends with } (right brace).** Each name is
>   followed by : (colon) and the name/value pairs are separated by ,
>   (comma).

Take note of the text I bolded.

Because of that, and JSON being JS *Object* Notation, it is implied that a JSON representation of a name:value pair must always be in the form of

```
{
  "name": "value"
}
```

Note that you can also make the 'root object' a list

```
[
  {
    "name1": "value1"
  },
  {
    "name2": "value2"
  }
]
```

This basically means that the JSON contains more than one object.

---

As Sunny R Gupta pointed out, this is also valid JSON

```
[
  "this",
  "is",
  "valid"
]
```

Note that this works because the strings are not in the form `"name":"value"` but just strings. Taking that into consideration valid options for your example would be

```
{
  "name": "Morpheus"
}
```

or

```
[
  "morpheus"
]
```

The first character of the JSON *must* be a `{` or a `[`

Comment: I beg to differ, the array could be even an array of strings, without `{}` and still constitute a valid JSON. e.g. `["This","is","valid"]`.

Comment: @SunnyRGupta you are correct saying that, but if you would make it `["a":"1", "b":"2"]` it would be invalid, because name/value pairs must be in `{}`, that is what I meant. Ill edit my answer to include your example though

Comment: Well, in that case let me point out `["name":"value"]` is not valid JavaScript in itself, so there is no point in clarifying (and confusing) regarding that case. I would recommend removing that section in itself. +1 for the detailed analysis.

Comment: @SunnyRGupta fair enough, I'll remove that to avoid confusion

Comment: This is wrong. That section (and especially the text in bold) just describes what an object is. There is a similar paragraph on arrays. Nowhere does it say that an object is the only permitted root value. Then again, it describes that a *value* may be an object, an array, but also a string, a number, etc.

Comment: @CRAM previous answer was indeed incorrect. I couldn't delete it because it is the accepted answer. I tried to rectify my statements just now in order to not spread false information. Please review the current answer and change it if you feel like it

Comment: It seems to exists many json specifications: 
* ecma404 (2013) only array and objects are valid (http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf)
* rfc7159 (2014) array, object, string, number, true, false, null are valid (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159)

Comment: This comment is wrong. RFC 4627 (2006) specified: "A JSON text is a serialized object or array." This restriction has been lifted in RFC 7159 (2014): "A JSON text is a serialized value." Your test in Python is still invalid in the new RFC since you should have typed `json.loads('"a"')` instead of `json.loads("a")` (all JSON texts should be contained in Python string objects).

Comment: @Maggyero can't disagree there. I have flagged this as a duplicate. This was always a garbage answer but I can't delete it

Answer (score 6):

It is valid in Javascript.

You might get confused at first trying to test this:

```
JSON.parse("bob");
```

This would fail with the error: "Unexpected token b".  However, that's the equivalent of passing just plain `bob` as the text in the response, not `"bob"`.  If you add the quotes:

```
JSON.parse('"bob"')
```

You get the simple string "bob" back as you should.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE: 2018**:

It has been 4 years since I originally answered this question. Back then plain strings in quotes were not valid JSON. As of today, it is being accepted as a valid JSON.

The following is kept for people to see what the error used to be earlier:

---

Parsing a simple string gives:

```
Parse error on line 1:
"morpheus"
^
Expecting '{', '['
```

indicating that it needs to be an object or an array.

**TIP:** To validate JSON strings and see what works and what does not, try using http://jsonlint.com

Comment: Actually, when I try it now (on that same page), it says "Valid JSON". Which is correct.

Comment: This answer is no longer correct, http://jsonlint.com now accepts `"morpheus"` as JSON.

Comment: Updated, thanks for pointing out the changes.